# Invalid greeting from server: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

The issue resides when trying to get incoming emails from the server side.
I simply get the error message Invalid greeting from server. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 const mailTransportTwo = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "outlook.office365.com",
  secure: true,
  port: 993,
  ssl: {
    ciphers: 'SSLv3'
  },
  auth: {
    user: '******************.com',
    pass: '******'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure od used port number and adding secureConnection to false worked for me

```
let normalTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.office365.com", //outlook.office365.com
    secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    tls: {
       ciphers:'SSLv3'
    },
    auth: {
        user: '********', // generated ethereal user 
        pass: '********', // generated ethereal password 
    }

});
```